# Unable to add product metadata to Stripe Checkout Session (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add some more information about my product when creating a Stipe Checkout Session, but the metadata doesn't pull through and Stripe just seems to ignore it. As far as I can tell I'm matching the docs perfectly:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product_data-metadata

Here is my code:

```php
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'shipping_address_collection' => [
        'allowed_countries' => ['GB']
    ],
    'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'gbp',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => $product->model->name,
                'images' => [
                    config('app.url') . $product->model->thumbnail->thumbnail_path
                ],
                'metadata' => [
                    'prod_id' => 'test_product_id'
                ]
            ],
            'unit_amount' => $product->model->price,
        ],
        'quantity' => $product->qty,
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => '***',
    'cancel_url' => '***',
]);
```

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you expected to see the metadata afterwards? You're adding `metadata` to a Product - are you inspecting a product object afterward?

If you want `metadata` on the session, you should add it at the top level of the session ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata)). If you want `metadata` on the payment intent created by checkout, you should include it within the `payment_intent_data` ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata)).